# Power BI slice by containing text with multiple selections

Tags: powerbi, analytics, slicers

I'm working with location data where each location has a primary category and many have one or multiple subcategories. The category and subcategory lists contain the same categories. I need to be able to slice by category so that any locations with a given category as a primary or sub category will show up. To do this I concatenate the category and sub-category  columns into one column and use the measure below to slice by if the concatenation column contains a certain category. The problem is when you select multiple categories from the slicer, the measure breaks and all the locations show up, not just the ones with the categories I want.

Measure = VAR searchvalue=Find(SELECTEDVALUE(Categories[Column1]),SELECTEDVALUE('Plant Demographics'[Catagorey Concat]),,Blank())
RETURN
If(searchvalue>0,"Found")

I got the measure from this post (https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Dynamic-filtering-slicing-if-text-contains/m-p/425504) and it works great with one selection but breaks with multiple in my dashboard and in the post I got it from. I've been trying to cycle through all selected values with a loop but power bi's support for loops is limited enough that I haven't had any luck. Any help would be appreciated.